# Can't UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox with Homebrew sshd

Tags: macos, homebrew, ssh

With OSX 10.9.5, and using the latest Homebrew OpenSSH, which at time of writing is OpenSSH_7.1p2/OpenSSL 1.0.2f, I *must set* the following in `/usr/local/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
```

(Or comment the line out entirely I suppose)

Just to get it to work. With it set to `sandbox` (which is the preferable and more secure default as I understand it), I get entries like this in my `/var/log/system.log`:

```
Feb  9 13:46:22 machine.local sshd[80808]: fatal: ssh_sandbox_child: sandbox_init: dlopen(/usr/lib/libsandbox.1.dylib, 261): image not found [preauth]
```

This seems like the behavior [prior to the MacPorts patches being added](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/issues/288) in late 2014. So how am I still seeing this issue? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I've got the same issue, except for me lib sandbox is complaining about the a preauth profile which seems to be missing